# Purge indexeddb in Android WebView programmatically - from Java/Kotlin, all origins

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, indexeddb

Need to erase IndexedDb in Android WebView, for all origins programmatically from Java/Kotlin - completely clear IndexedDb, nuke it. Searched posts, tried below - none work as of 10/2018.

```
// none work below as of 10/2018
mWebView.clearCache(true);         // IndexedDbs remain
deleteCache(this); // recursively deletes context.getCacheDir(), IndexedDbs remain
deleteDatabase("webview.db");      // db does not exist
deleteDatabase("webviewCache.db"); // db does not exist
```

Seen solutions purging IndexedDb in Linux - not acceptable for WebView. Seen solutions deleting individual databases from JS (I can inject JS into Webview) - not acceptable since all origins may not be known.
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is good that it is not working. That would be a big security issue. 
Imagine an app purging all indexeddb stores from **all origins** on your device.

You can only deal with an indexeddb store within the origin you created it.